# How to position the div at the bottom of the window?

Tags: css, html, css-position

For a division to place at the top or somewhere in the window we will give some relative margin for it. Is there any way to set the div at the bottom, like just above the footer? I will give explanation for my question:
I have a footer.
I have a div with height = 200px
I have another div with height = 400px
Now I want to place them in the window, such that they should look like, they are placed on the footer. How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main content should be something like this:

```
.wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -40em; /* The -40em should be adjusted to your page, just play around with it */
}
```

Then goes your div heitgh200, div height400 and footer.

Here is a full working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bn72w/1/

Here is a good tutorial on sticky footers: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/